# The type org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I am getting the following error, when i tried to create my first application in Spring Tool Suite:

> Multiple markers at this line
>               - The type org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is 
>                indirectly referenced from required .class files
>               - The method run(Object, String...) from thae type SpringApplication refers to the missing type 
>                ConfigurableApplicationContext

**This is the following pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>com.welcome</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>

        <name>welcome</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>



        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>



    This is the Controller Used


    package com.welcome.demo;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class WelcomeApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
            SpringApplication.run(WelcomeApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Can any one help in this? what is my mistake? And it is showing red exclamation mark on the project folder.

Comment: Hard to say. But something is missing from the classpath it seems. Could be a problem with the pom, or it could be maven/m2e hasn't yet properly downloaded all the dependencies and added them to the eclipse classpath. Try to use the 'update project' action from the project's 'Maven' context menu. If that doesn't help its likely you need to add something to the pom to get some required dependencies.

Comment: If it worked for you, you should click to accept [bpjoshi's answer](/a/42045812/3127111)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your maven cache is corrupted. To resolve this problem, follow the steps below:

- Go to the directory of your project on the command line.
- Make sure your POM.xml is in the same directory as your command line
- Run the command

  ```
  mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
  ```
- If you receive **build successful** message, means the error has been resolved.
- If error is still there, delete your (~/.m2/repository/org/springframework) folder and run

  ```
  mvn package
  ```

It will work properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the spring-boot-starter-parent to latest version . Resolved the problem for me

```
<parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      **<version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version> // update this to latest**
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```