# Maven error ContextConfigApplicationContext cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I tried to import the spring starter pom.xml in my Eclipse Luna. I was getting the below error. I dont remember getting this error before after I installed and reinstalled it. Any thoughts

```
The type org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

I tried the below thread, but didnt help.

https://java.net/jira/browse/PINEAPPLE-764

Answer (score 1):

Your maven cache seems corrupted. You need to purge local repository.

See my answer at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42045812/3148734) for the detailed steps to solve this problem.