# Spring Security samples from official GitHub repository doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I follow along with the tutorial [Hello Spring Security with Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-boot.html#running-the-insecure-application) to learn Spring Security.
After importing it into STS，I got build errors:

```
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:jar is missing.
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar is missing.
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar is missing.
```

I thought the sample comes from **official GitHub repository,** so it should work well. Unfortunately, I encounter build errors.

Then I tried to fix the build errors. I appended `<version>1.5.3.release</version>` tags in POM file and the errors from POM file disappeared.
But I still encountered an error from main class:

```
The type org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Comment: check force update of snapshopts and update project in eclipse it clears some corrupted jar in the repository

Comment: @ramvinoth It doesn't work.

Comment: It shows your jar file is missing so the version updated in pom file doesn't match with the jar. so try clearing .m2 folder and build your project once again.

Comment: how do you configure your spring security. through xml or java configuration?

Comment: Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512340/the-type-org-springframework-context-configurableapplicationcontext-cannot-be-re/42045812#42045812

Comment: @ramvinoth I haven't configure spring security yet. I just import that example without configuring spring security.

Answer (score -1):

I have used all spring samples from official site and it works.

my sample pom file is as below,

https://github.com/Roshanmutha/rcmutha-springrest/blob/master/pom.xml

Only  will have addition and removal as per the sample you are trying.

Click the below link to see all sample which i have tried from spring repo :

https://github.com/Roshanmutha?utf8=%E2%9C%93&tab=repositories&q=rcmutha&type=&language=

Comment: Hello.. May i know what you need ? Please share me your code in Github. i will have look.

Comment: Thanks. The link is [here](https://github.com/niaomingjian/spring-security-samples-boot/tree/fromofficialrep).

Comment: Looks like Its your set up issue.I have forked your git repo and able to run sample as it is without any errror. Fork used : https://github.com/Roshanmutha/spring-security-samples-boot. Do few more steps, 1. Delete all content from C:\Users\{user}\.m2\repository and do mvn install and try to run the sample.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. `Master` branch is the version that I've modified. `fromofficialrep` [branch](https://github.com/Roshanmutha/spring-security-samples-boot/tree/fromofficialrep) is the one that's from official repository.

Comment: You mean `fromofficialrep` branch also works well in your environment?

Comment: Official and yours (https://github.com/niaomingjian/spring-security-samples-boot/tree/fromofficialrep) both works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145516/discussion-between-roshankumar-mutha-and-niaomingjian).